# reset a docker image with a database

Tags: docker

I would like to have a snapshot from a 300GB database, do some testing on it until the database is not in a testable state anymore and then "reset" the database to it's snapshot state and test again.

Docker seems a good fit for this, but all I can find is how to setup an empty database with sql server.

Is it possible to create a docker image with sqlserver installed and an existing database of 300GB inside the image? And then pull the image again to reset the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes.  In practice, you'll hit two big problems:

1. All of the standard Docker Hub database images are configured so that their data *always* lives in a volume.  This means that you can't create an image based on the standard images with data preloaded; you'll have to create your own base database image.
2. Docker's network I/O starts to get flaky with single layers that are much above 1 GB.  Simply the mechanics of transferring a 300 GB image across the network will be troublesome.

There are also some considerations depending on how the database internally stores its data.  If there is a single 300 GB file, it's possible that the first write to it will result in trying to copy the whole thing.  This is dependent on the database storage and low-level Linux kernel details that you don't generally have access to or control over.

It might be better to embrace Docker's volume system than to try to coerce an image into doing this for you.  Consider that you can start a container with external data, stop and delete it, then start a new container based on the same data; if you save a copy of the underlying data files in between, the database won't know that you're restarting it from a snapshot.

Mocking this out with PostgreSQL, you could do something like:

```sh
# Start a database container, pointing at local data
docker run \
  -d \
  --name postgres \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -v "$PWD:pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data" \
  postgres:13
# Seed the database
PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=5432 ./seed-data.py
# Stop the database
docker stop postgres
docker rm postgres
# Save a copy of the database data
tar cvzf pgdata.tar.gz pgdata
```

Then each time you want to run a test, you can unpack this saved data tree

```sh
rm -rf pgdata
tar xzf pgdata.tar.gz
docker run \
  -d \
  --name postgres \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -v "$PWD:pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data" \
  postgres:13
PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=5432 ./integration-test.py
```

With 300 GB of data, it will still take some time to decompress and write out the tar file, but this at least is straightforward and only relies on ordinary tooling.